# Spring authorization server: Registration access token rotation

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I am using Spring authorization server and have configured the clients to have short lived access tokens.
When a new client is registered a registration access token is issued, which then the client can use to view/modify client properties at client configuration end point. While issuing this token, spring is using the token settings configured for the client to set the expiry of the the registration access token.

While I want my access tokens to be short lived, I  still want the clients to have access to view/modify the client details by calling client configuration end point using registration access token.
Currently once the token is expired there is no way to view the client properties once token is expired. Is registration access token rotation supported in spring authorization server? Is there a way to refresh registration access token?

I see that I can increase the token time to live settings using the token settings for the client. But I would like to set a shorter time for access tokens and have refresh/rotate logic for registration access token.